# android-async-http onProgress posting file doesn't work

Tags: android, post, file-upload, asyncfileupload, android-async-http

I uploaded a file to a PHP server using [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http):

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
AsyncHttpResponseHandler httpResponseHandler = createHTTPResponseHandler();
File file =new File(filePath);
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("data", file); 
client.post(context, url, params, httpResponseHandler);
```

This works fine WITH PROGRESS,

But when I use these code to upload a file to a .NET server it 
DOESN'T WORK, I solved it by putting a file in HttpEntity like this:

```
HttpEntity entity = new FileEntity(file, "multipart/form-data");
client.post(context, url, entity, "multipart/form-data", httpResponseHandler);
```

It worked fine WITH NO PROGRESS, JUST ONE FLUSH.

I need to show progress while is the file uploading.
Thanks.

Comment: did you solve it?